# Add an icon to html through css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I was wondering what the possibility of adding an icon to a `<td>` item through css. Currently in my table (using angular) if a certain value (score) is greater that 75% I make the row in the table red. That is a bit intrusive so since I am using font-awesome elsewhere on the page I though maybe I might try adding a star next to the score. To change to red I am using `ng-style` and calling a method which evaluates the score, then sets the css accordingly.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat=" item in infractions | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="launchIAT()" ng-style="setColor(item.score)">
    <td>{{$index + 1}} </td>
    <td>{{item.name.replace("_"," ")}}</td>
    <td>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>
</tr>
```

And here is the `setColor()` method in the js:

```
$scope.setColor = function(score){
    if (score >= 75){
        return { background: '#FF4747', color : '#FFFFFF' }
    }else if( score >= 50 && score < 75){
        return {background : '#FFFF47' }
    }
};
```

I was wondering the possibility of maybe using an `ng-show` though I didnt know if inside `ng-show` you could call a method. Like show if it's greater than 75% kinda thing? I would just ideally like  `<i class="fa fa-star"></i>` to show next to `{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}` when greater than 75%.

What is the best solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would add a css class that uses `::before`

Comment: Would the fact that this table update live affect that in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the fontawesome styleshet https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css you'll be able to pick out the .fa-star section...

```
.fa-star:before {
  content: "\f005";
}
```

You could use this on your td's, with aether a class or directly.

```
 td {
    position: relative;
font-family: FontAwesome;
    }
        td:before /* OR */ td.class:before {
          content: "\f005";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you  want with the ng-show directive however, a better option is to use the ng-class directive as follows

```
ng-class="{className:score > 75%}"
```

where className will be replaced with the name of the css class

Comment: so something like: `<td ng-class="{fa-star: item.score >= 75}">{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>` because that doesn't provide the desired results.

Comment: not exactly, try <td><i ng-class="{fa-star: item.score >= 75}"></i>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>